# How to print a text file using PrintDialog in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to `C#` windows forms.

I am trying to print the content of a Text file using the `PrintDialog` as shown in screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yWmL.jpg)

The following code is working correctly and it is printing but the printing process occurs immediately without opening the `PrintDialog`. I want to open the `PrintDialog` because I have 3 printers and I want to select a specific printer and when I click `OK` I want to print it.

Anyone knows how to modify this code so it can display the `PrintDialog` box so I can select a printer and continue printing?.

```
 private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string filename = @"D:\\File1.txt";
        //Create a StreamReader object  
        reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        //Create a Verdana font with size 10  
        verdana10Font = new Font("Verdana", 10);
        //Create a PrintDocument object  
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        //Add PrintPage event handler  
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintTextFileHandler);
        //Call Print Method  
        pd.Print();
        //Close the reader  
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();

        }



    private void PrintTextFileHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs)
        {
        //Get the Graphics object  
        Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = 0;



        float topMargin = 50;
        string line = null;
        //Calculate the lines per page on the basis of the height of the page and the height of the font  
        linesPerPage = ppeArgs.MarginBounds.Height / verdana10Font.GetHeight(g);
        //Now read lines one by one, using StreamReader  
        while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
            //Calculate the starting position  
            yPos = topMargin + (count * verdana10Font.GetHeight(g));
            //Draw text  
            g.DrawString(line, verdana10Font, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
            //Move to next line  
            count++;
            }
        //If PrintPageEventArgs has more pages to print  
        if (line != null)
            {
            ppeArgs.HasMorePages = true;
            }
        else
            {
            ppeArgs.HasMorePages = false;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Did you tried example from official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using PrintDialog.

```
PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
pdialog.Document = pd;
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pd.Print();
}
```

Complete Code

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintTextFileHandler);
PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
pdialog.Document = pd;
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pd.Print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code but it does not show the printDialoge box.  can you help please?

Comment: If you are using 64bit machine, you might have to set pdialog.UseEXDialog = True. Let me know if that works

Comment: yes i use 64bit and after i added UseEXDialoge=true the PrintDialoge box shows up but when i click Print it throws error at this line " linesPerPage = ppeArgs.MarginBounds.Height / verdana10Font.GetHeight(g);"   it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"   any idea why? thanks

Comment: You might have to debug that a bit, seems like some variable / property is not set. You would have to hit the debugger and check values of each variable in that line

Comment: Anu Viswan- thank you but I still did not resolve it sir. I am new to C# and i did not know which  variable / property is not set. I will be regretful if you could check from your side

Comment: @Toni it might be extremely hard for me to check this unless i see the entire program or you debug it.  Following link might be useful for you to understand how to use the debugger. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017.